# Inserting a closing tag in a database display

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that's styled to display a question followed by several answer choices, with the question and each answer wrapped in a div. However, I'd like the entire thing to be wrapped in an outer div (or section, actually), like this...

```
<section class="OuterWrapper">
  <div>Question</div>
  <div>Answer A</div>
  <div>Answer B</div>
  <div>Answer C</div>
</section>
```

I can easily insert the first part...

```
<section class="OuterWrapper">
```

But I can't figure out where or how to insert the closing tag. Can anyone show me how to do it?

```
$Q1 = null;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
$QID = $row['QID'];
$URL = $row['URL'];
$Value = $row['Value'];
$Question = $row['Question'];
$Answer = $row['Answer'];
$Correct = $row['Correct'];
$Correct = str_replace('1', 'correct', $Correct);
$Correct = str_replace('2', 'wrong', $Correct);

$Q2 = '  <form action="" method="post" id="quiz">
<div style="margin-top: 10px;">'.$Question.'</div>';

if ($row["Question"] != $Q1) {
 $Q1 = $row["Question"];
 echo "{$Q2}\n";
}

echo '<div class="Answer '.$Correct.'"><input type="radio" name="'.$QID.'" id="quiz"   value="'.$Value.'" /> '.$Answer.'</div>' . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just `echo` the markup where you want it on the page?  I don't see what the issue is here.

Comment: !!! Simply after the end of while loop.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the display consists of SEVERAL questions, each followed by several answers. So if I put the closing tag after the questions inside the loop, I get a closing tag after every question. But if I put the closing tag outside the loop, then I get a closing tag after ten questions, instead of after each question-and-answer set.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. Where the while loop  closing bracket ends:

```
        echo '<div class="Answer '.$Correct.'"><input type="radio" name="'.$QID.'" id="quiz"   value="'.$Value.'" /> '.$Answer.'</div>' . "\n";
    }

    echo '</section>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just echo the keyword. Use the code below

```
    $Q1 = null;
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $QID = $row['QID'];
    $URL = $row['URL'];
    $Value = $row['Value'];
    $Question = $row['Question'];
    $Answer = $row['Answer'];
    $Correct = $row['Correct'];
    $Correct = str_replace('1', 'correct', $Correct);
    $Correct = str_replace('2', 'wrong', $Correct);

    $Q2 = '  <form action="" method="post" id="quiz">
    <div style="margin-top: 10px;">'.$Question.'</div>';

    if ($row["Question"] != $Q1) {
     $Q1 = $row["Question"];
     echo "{$Q2}\n";
    }

    echo '<div class="Answer '.$Correct.'"><input type="radio" name="'.$QID.'" id="quiz"   value="'.$Value.'" /> '.$Answer.'</div>' . "\n";
    }
 echo '</section>';
```

Hope this helps you